Create array of structs pyspark with named fields
I would like to pass a list of strings - which are column names - into a transform function which results in a new column containing an array of structs with two fields - "key" and "value". Where key is the column name and value is the corresponding column value
data = [
    Row(name='Alice', age=30, city='New York'),
    Row(name='Bob', age=25, city='Los Angeles'),
    Row(name='Charlie', age=35, city='Chicago')
]

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

I currently have:
df_with_column_of_structs = df.withColumn('array_of_structs', 
                                          expr(f"TRANSFORM(array(name, age), col -> named_struct('key', 'col', 'val', col))")
                                         )
df_with_column_of_structs.printSchema()
df_with_column_of_structs.show(truncate=False)

// output 
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- array_of_structs: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- val: string (nullable = true)

+-------+---+-----------+---------------------------+
|name   |age|city       |array_of_structs           |
+-------+---+-----------+---------------------------+
|Alice  |30 |New York   |[{col, Alice}, {col, 30}]  |
|Bob    |25 |Los Angeles|[{col, Bob}, {col, 25}]    |
|Charlie|35 |Chicago    |[{col, Charlie}, {col, 35}]|
+-------+---+-----------+---------------------------+


my desired output is
|name   |age|city       |array_of_structs           |
+-------+---+-----------+---------------------------+
|Alice  |30 |New York   |[{name, Alice}, {age, 30}]  |
|Bob    |25 |Los Angeles|[{name, Bob}, {age, 25}]    |
|Charlie|35 |Chicago    |[{name, Charlie}, {age, 35}]|
+-------+---+-----------+---------------------------+

however I am unable to dereferecne the column name to accomplish this. I have tried using both $ and {} to derefernce but have gotten syntax errors for both
i.e.
df_with_column_of_structs = df.withColumn('array_of_structs', 
                                          expr(f"TRANSFORM(array(name, age), col -> named_struct('key', {col}, 'val', col))")
                                         )
//output 
An error was encountered:
name 'col' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'col' is not defined


This is not really your output as a struct is defined as a key value (key: value) pair. You are using komma as separator (key, value).
Maybe this is helpful.
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    Row(name='Alice', age=30, city='New York'),
    Row(name='Bob', age=25, city='Los Angeles'),
    Row(name='Charlie', age=35, city='Chicago')
]

schema=StructType([
    StructField(name="name", dataType=StringType()),
    StructField(name="age", dataType=IntegerType()),
    StructField(name="city", dataType=StringType())
])

df = (
    spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
    .withColumn("nested_struct", f.array(f.struct("name", "age")))
)


